# Javascript Placeholder Polyfill

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

I was wondering if you could review the following code I've written as a polyfill for the placeholder attribute in HTML5?

The object of the polyfill is to replicate the functionality of the placeholder attribute. In effect, the polyfill is supposed to do the following:

1. Default text to be shown.
2. On Focus: Erase the default text.
3. On Focus Out: Put in default text if nothing has been entered

Dependancies:

1. jQuery

   ```
   var Utils = Utils || {};

   Utils = (function (window, $) { 

       var _c, _private, _public;

       _private = {

           /**
            * @event
            * @param e The event object.
            */
           'handleFocusIn': function (e) {
               var $target = $(e.currentTarget);
               if($target.val() === $target.attr('placeholder')) {
                   $target.val('');
               }
               $target
                   .unbind('focusin')
                   .bind('focusout', _private.handleFocusOut);
           },

           /**
            * @event
            * @param e The event object.
            */
           'handleFocusOut': function (e) {
               var $target = $(e.currentTarget);
               if($target.val() === '') {
                   $target.val($target.attr('placeholder'));
               }
               $target
                   .unbind('focusout')
                   .bind('focusin', _private.handleFocusIn);
           }
       };

       _public = {
           /**
            * @function
            * @description
            * A poly-fill for the placeholder attribute.
            */
           'supportsPlaceholderAttr': function (enableFallback) {
               var placeHolderSupported = false;

               //If enableFallback is either undefined or not a Boolean, set it to false
               if((typeof enableFallback === 'undefined') || !(enableFallback instanceof Boolean)) {
                   enableFallback = false;
               }

               //if placeholder is supported, no reason to continue on
               if ('placeholder' in document.createElement("input")) {
                   return placeHolderSupported = true;
               }

               if (!placeHolderSupported && !!enableFallback) {
                   var $inputEle;
                   $('input')
                       .each( function(index, ele) {
                           $inputEle = $(ele);
                           if($inputEle.attr('placeholder')) {
                               $inputEle
                                   .val($inputEle.attr('placeholder'))
                                   .bind('focusin', _private.handleFocusIn);
                           }
                       });
               }
           }
       };

       return _public;

   }(window, jQuery));
   ```

Comment: [fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/HWKKa/)

Comment: @Raynos I liked how you shortened up the code, however what if I wanted to extend shim to have more than just the polyfill for the placeholder attribute? Also, there are no checks for the enableFallback parameter - shouldn't best practices have you check for that value?

Comment: [mocked](http://jsfiddle.net/RJhn4/)

Comment: I checked with `enableFallback && run loop`. i used a short circuiting trickery to make sure you only bunch the focusin/out handlers in if the enableFallback flag is set

Comment: @Raynos not sure if you're taking IE into consideration? handleFocusIn/handleFocusOut binds/unbinds due to the nature of IE7 mobile. Perhaps I wasn't clear on what devices this would support. As for _c, _private and _public; they were just included for extensibility (_c = cached variables, _private for the event handlers and _public for the actual supportsPlaceholderAttr method. Although I can re-name them anytime - an no I'm not familiar with Java.

Comment: @alvincrespo Could you elaborate on or link to some information regarding "the nature of IE7 mobile"?

Comment: @RyanKinal What I mean by "IE7 Mobile" - I mean that the focusIn and focusOut event happens several times upon focusing in on the input field, thus causing the events to trigger to many times. So I bind/unbind based on the current action of the user. This also goes hand in hand with predicting user interaction and only using what you need.

Comment: Ah, yes. `focusin` and `focusout` will bubble. If, however, you use `focus`, and `blur`, that will solve your problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** Regarding the OP's comment on the "nature of IE7 mobile", I suspect it has more to do with jQuery's implementation of `focusin` and `focusout`. This may not be the case, but I have written my review with that assumption in mind.

There are a few things about your code that are, to put it bluntly, pointless.

First, checking whether `Utils` exists is a good thing, but you then immediately clobber it with the return of your function:

```
var Utils = Utils || {};

Utils = (function(window, $) {
    /* ... */
    return _public;
})(window, jQuery);
```

Something like the following would most likely be better:

```
var Utils = Utils || (function(window, $) {
    /* ... */
    return _public;
})(window, jQuery);
```

Second, why pass `window` to the function at all? Browsers will not allow overwriting of the `window` object, and your parameter name is `window` anyway, so it doesn't save you anything.

Third, `_private` is unnecessary. Any variables (including functions) that you don't include in whatever object you return will be hidden by the local scope of your self-executing function.

```
var handleFocusIn = function(e) { /*...*/ },
    handleFocusOut = function(e) { /*...*/ };
```

`_public` is also unnecessary, though not as much as `_private`. If it were me, I would simply return the object literal, rather than bothering with the `_public` variable.

Lastly, given that your elements will always be `input` elements, there is no need to use `focusin` and `focusout`; Simply use `focus` and `blur` - this will avoid any possible bubbling issues, and then, most importantly, allow you to dispense with the unbinding/rebinding that happens in your handlers.

@Raynos also makes some good points on your implementation of `supportsPlaceHolderAttr`, regarding variables and conditionals.

```
//if placeholder is supported, no reason to continue on
if ('placeholder' in document.createElement("input")) {
    // useless variable, just return true
    return placeHolderSupported = true;
}

// useless placeHoldSupported check, always false. Useless enableFallback conversion always a bool
if (!placeHolderSupported && !!enableFallback) {
```

It's a good attempt at writing unobtrusive code, but it falls short of good modularity and namespacing. Still, like I said, a good start.

Comment: Passing `window` into an anoymous closure is a tiny micro optimisation (one less layer of lookup) and allows you to minify the `window` variable.

Comment: Point taken. +1

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. A clear explanation of why my code doesn't really make sense - if it doesn't. Thanks so much @RyanKinal It was clear and to the point and definitely helps me improve. Any more answers/suggestions would be great. :)

Comment: I added a suggestion on the idea of detecting whether `Utils` exists.